# Why Sikhism isn't a philosophical school in Hinduism?

Tags: philosophy, other-religions

[Sikhism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sikhism) is a religion that has the concept of reincarnation and pantheism like Hinduism. 
 They reject vedas like jainism and Buddhism.

So why it isn't a philosophical school even thou it follows almost all the philosophy in Hinduism.

Comment: All religions that don't accept Vedas generally are not sanathanic in nature.

Comment: @hanugm yes, but jainism and Buddhism also do not accept but still they are called nastika.

Comment: @DarkKnight Nastika is a classification in INDIAN philosophy, not HINDU philosophy. Astika = Hindu. Nastika = non-Hindu. Abrahamic religions, Buddhism, Jainism, Charvaka, Sikhism, Mayan religion, etc. are all nastikas.

Comment: Sikhism is very much part of Hinduism though a military school. They’re part of the slightly modified version of Hinduism we’re following nowadays. Only difference is besides normal Hinduism they’re supposed to follow certain other practices. But their Granth mentions ‘ek Omkar ek sat naam’ Omkar is the true name, in accordance with the Upanishads. They’re only the Punjabi/Kshatriya faction of Hindus who were formed to curb the oppression of Aurangzeb and the like. Today’s politics considers them different

Comment: all orthodox schools, astika, of Hinduism accept the vedas. To not accept the vedas is heterodox, nastika. This is a duplicate question

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda so why Sikhism isn't a nastika school

Comment: @Ikshvaku Sikhism is also a Indian philosophy like Buddhism

Comment: @DarkKnight read my comment it’s not a separate philosophy

Comment: @Archit it is a separate philosophy, they do not believe in idol worship, they reject vedas(nastika) they wear head covering and there way of worship is different from hindus (similar to Muslims).

Comment: @Archit Oneness of God is at the core of Hinduism although it has some pantheistic and henotheistic tendencies.

Description of God in Sikhism is monotheistic and rejects the concept of divine incarnation as present in Hinduism [hindu and sikh](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism_and_Sikhism#:~:text=Oneness%20of%20God%20is%20at,incarnation%20as%20present%20in%20Hinduism.)

Comment: It depends on the sect of Sikhism. The Udasi sect, for example, follows Vedanta.

Comment: @PradipGangopadhyay over all Sikhism (in general) is not a school of thought in Hinduism. Why.

Comment: Sikhism is considered to be Vaishnavism. Vaishnavs consider only Narayana/Vishnu to be God and may be considered to be monotheists. Sikhs are also monotheists. There is no new philosophy in Sikhism.